# How to print cumulative sums of successive columns for each row ina matrix?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix

I have a (square) matrix of correlations and I want to explicitly print cumulative sums of squares of elements in a row, for all rows. For example, it should print out something like "The variance in variable 3 due to the first 7 principal components is <sum of elements in the first 7 columns of the 3rd row>" and so on. I tried the following:

```
Fmat ## the original matrix (of correlations)

s <- matrix(data=NA, nrow=nrow(Fmat), ncol=ncol(Fmat)) ## create an empty matrix of cumulative sums

for (i in 1:nrow(Fmat)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(Fmat)) {
    s[i, j] <- s + (Fmat[i, j])^2
    print(paste("Variance in variable", i, "due to the first", j, "PCs is", s[i, j]))
  }
}
```

I get

```
Error in s[i, j] <- s + (Fmat[i, j])^2 : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I had tried declaring s to be a scalar and not a matrix but it went on to cumulate column values over all the rows instead of starting the cumulative process again for each new row.

I guess the problem is with the following line

```
s[i, j] <- s + (Fmat[i, j])^2
```

Comment: The last line is the issue, s is a matrix, while Fmat[i,j] is a number, you can add these two together to obtain a new matrix s where each element has incremented by Fmat[i,j], however you cannot now assign this new matrix to one element of an existing matrix, i.e. s[i,j]. What exactly do you want to compute in this last line?

Comment: I suspect that what they intended was something like `s[i, j] <- (if (j > 1L) s[i, j - 1L] else 0) + Fmat[i, j]^2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` to precompute the cumulative sums you want to print, like so:

```r
X <- t(apply(Fmat * Fmat, 1L, cumsum))
n <- nrow(Fmat)
for (i in seq_len(n)) {
  for (j in seq_len(n)) {
    cat("Variance in variable", i, "due to the first", j, "PCs is", X[i, j], "\n")
  }
}
```

Here, row `i` of matrix `X` contains the cumulative sum of the squared elements of row `i` of matrix `Fmat`.

To avoid an explicit `for` loop, you can also do this:

```r
f <- function(x, i, j) {
  cat("Variance in variable", i, "due to the first", j, "PCs is", x, "\n")
}
invisible(Map(f, x = t(X), i = t(row(X)), j = t(col(X))))
```